# Find the coords of the dots

Tags: math, geometry

[image]

there are 2 nodes

```
const nodes = [
  { width: 170, height: 77, x: 50, y: 100 },
  { width: 206, height: 125, x: 350, y: 100 }
];
```

- Yellow dot - coords of top-left corner of the node
- Red dot - center of the node
- Green line between 2 nodes
- Blue point - point where the line intersects the boundaries of the
  node coordinates for each such point

I would like to find the coordinates of the blue dots, relative to the upper-left corner of their parent node (yellow dots)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58055928/844416